# Backbone Validation firing multiple times

Tags: backbone.js

I'm wondering why the Validate method on my model runs multiple times when I add a model to a collection.

Even if I strip my model Validation right down to this...

```
Client.Model = Backbone.Model.extend ({

    validate : function(attrs) {
        if ( !attrs.first_name ){
            return 'Required';
        }   
    }  

});
```

If I console.log() from inside the validate method I can see that it's been called 5 times. the first two validate successfully, the third fails, and then the 4th and 5th also pass (and subsequently it syncs correctly on the server)

This is creating a problem because I'm building a custom message plugin and it's being called all 5 times that the validation occurs.

I know it will correctly be called when I create a new model and retrieve models from the server. But  what I cannot understand is this 'third' call to validate that always fails. (btw, I've managed to figure out that it is NOT a server issue)

I'm wondering what i'm missing here..

Thanks in advance.

:)

JSBIN  - http://jsbin.com/ucowoq/2/edit

Check the console, obviously there's an error with the POST, but it shows the validate method running 5 times, on my app, it fails to validate on the 3rd every time! The server only ever returns a 500 error or the JSON for the created model.

Hope this helps anyone looking over this.

EDIT : 
I've come up with this hack to get everything working correctly. I'm still not happy with the validate method being called 5 times, but because the 1 occurrence that caused the validation to fail contained an object with key & 'undefined' values, I'm just checking for that before returning anything. This allows me to implement my 'message' plugin as I can now retrieve errors at the correct time.

```
    validate: function( attrs ){
      if (attrs.first_name !== undefined){
        if (!attrs.first_name)
          return 'first name required';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined ... on the jsbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that causes this confusion here is this: [Backbone 0.9.9 Line 411](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/0.9.9/backbone.js#L411) It clears the model's attributes before setting them again.

Why does it matter though? It will fail to validate, true, but the result of that validation is never used anywhere, so you shouldn't need that check for undefined in your edit.

Comment: It matters because if you want to send error messages from the server then you need to retrieve them via the error response callback & without the hack shown above, you'll get that false validation causing confusion.